# particular integral of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $P(x,y)$ be a particular integral of the partial differential equation   $$z_{xx} -z_y= 2y -x^2$$  Then $P(2,3)$ equals  (a) 2  (b) 8  (c) 12  (d) 10

Answer (score 0):

Trying a 3rd degree polynomial solution
$$z=a+b x+c y+d x y+e x^2+f y^2+g x^3+h x^2 y+i x y^2+j y^3 $$
gives a 4-parameter family of solutions
$$a+b x+e x^2+2 e y+g x^3+6 g x y+x^2 y$$
which could have any value at the point $(2,3)$.

Comment: exactly which value?

Comment: @user158150 it seems that all values are possible.